# How to make MySQL sort rows form the Latest created

Tags: php, mysql

I have a doubt here, Is there any way you can tell MySQL to Align or Sort out rows from the newest to the oldest, for an Example I created 2 rows in my Database the First one Hi World And the second one Hello World,Instead of showing from the latest It show's it alpabatically But I want It to show from the newest to the oldest How to have That kind effect? I've even tried using `SELECT * FROM pages ORDER BY postID ASC` but It does not Work! Please help me.

the Browse tab of the pages table:

[image]

the Structure tab of the pages table:

[image]

Comment: Please can you provide more information about the `pages` table?

Comment: Add a column which stores the date the row was added, then sort by it.

Comment: Do you have a `created_datetime` in your row?

Comment: This is woefully short of information (although `postid DESC` seems like an obvious solution)

Comment: I've provided some Images, Sorry for the late response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

> SELECT * FROM pages ORDER BY postID DESC

to show the latest first (ASC is ascendent)

Comment: Note that the post id does not necessarily correlate with age.

Comment: It just changes from A-Z to Z-A. Is It not possible to make them align by the latest to the oldest?

Comment: Ah I see now. You probably just need to create another field and define it as primary key (integer)

Comment: By the way, your field 'postDate' could be misunderstood if someone work on your code later. Just for semantics, but maybe you could call it 'postData' :)

Comment: Awesome, I created a new row called postNum and added it as primary key A_I to have a number of every article then made it DESC and It works!!! Tahnk you @Dimas Pante

Answer (score 1):

If you order them by `postID ASC`, it's from the smallest to the biggest one. The smallest one will be the oldest one, so this is not what you want.

Change the `ASC` by `DESC`, and it should work.

```
SELECT * FROM pages ORDER BY postID DESC
```

Comment: Note that the post id does not necessarily correlate with age.

Comment: It just changes from A-Z to Z-A. Is It not possible to make them align by the latest to the oldest?

Comment: If the smallest ID isn't the oldest entry, then I'm not sure what you can do. If your `postDate` was a `DATETIME` or other time format, you would be able to sort it with that, but in your case it's a `VARCHAR` with HTML, I don't know what you can do with that. - **EDIT ** Just noticed the pictures you added in your first post. I really don't know what can be done with that,  all your fields but `isRoot` are `VARCHAR` or `TEXT`, and they will be sorted alphabetically as you noticed.